# How to use next redux wrapper the correct way?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux for state mgmt in my Next 13 app. i started working on my project moment after vercel introduced Next JS 13. but recently i upgraded my project to the latest version and it kind of broke down.

in the previous version the `export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);` has been showing some kind of warning but it works. Now, it still works but it always throw an error when i navigate to a page where it uses redux.

```
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

i wrapped the the root layout with wrapper i created inside the store.

/layout.js

```
"use client";

import "../styles/globals.css";

import { wrapper } from "../store";
import { AuthProvider } from "./AuthProvider";
import NextTopLoader from "nextjs-toploader";

function RootLayout({ children }) {
  // const { store } = wrapper.useWrappedStore();
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <AuthProvider>
          <NextTopLoader color="#008080" showSpinner={false} />
          {children}
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
// export default RootLayout;
export default wrapper.withRedux(RootLayout);
```

store.js

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE } from "next-redux-wrapper";
import menuReducer from "./slices/menuSlice";
import livingReducer from "./slices/livingSlice";
import vehicleReducer from "./slices/vehicleSlice";
import blogReducer from "./slices/blogSlice";
import sellHomeReducer from "./slices/sellHomeSlice";
import sellVehicleReducer from "./slices/sellVehicleSlice";
import {} from "react-redux";
import { ActionTypes } from "@mui/base";

// const store = configureStore({
//   reducer: {
//     menu: menuReducer,
//     living: livingReducer,
//   },
// });
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  menu: menuReducer,
  living: livingReducer,
  vehicle: vehicleReducer,
  blog: blogReducer,
  sellHome: sellHomeReducer,
  sellVehicle: sellVehicleReducer,
});

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (ActionTypes.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState = {
      ...state,
      ...action.payload,
    };
    return nextState;
  } else {
    return combinedReducer(state, action);
  }
};
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducer,
});

const makeStore = () => store;

export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);
```

well the issue is that the redux performs as expected but the error is displayed on the screen and in terminal.

screen error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

terminal error

```
- error node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useReduxContext.js (30:0) @ useReduxContext
- error Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
    at MobileFilter (./app/products/MobileFilter.jsx:34:76)
null
```

package versions

```
"react-redux": "^8.0.5",
"next-redux-wrapper": "^8.0.0",
```

why is this happening now and how can i fix this? or even if there is another approach for this i will accept